# Hyper-V: 'machine' could not initialize

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I looked for a lot of articles regarding my problem, but none of them seem to explain this particular behavior.
I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 installed as a host OS and a Hyper-V role enabled.
I have 4 virtual machines, which were working like a charm until yesterday. The core environment didn't change, everything was working well, but at one moment all VMs stop working. When I try to start any of them (or new one created) it says: 'machine' could not initialize. Where the 'machine' is a VM name.

NOTE: they were working on this host without any issues. They were working, they were started. The machine was not rebooted and nothing was installed there. They just stopped working at one moment.

I checked BIOS - the Intel Hardware Virtualization is enabled. The test tool shows that the Hardware D.E.P is enabled.

*UPDATE:*
The machine was rebooted after BSOD.

Comment: Please check the errror logs in eventveiwer if possible send the full error code which you are getting

Comment: This is the ONLY error message I see in Hyper-V-Worker event log. No other events are stored neither in System nor in Application or other sections: `'DG-BUILD3' could not initialize. (Virtual machine ID 2C894C55-E6B0-4F92-9FD8-55338EB7A543)`

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing after the host blue screened. Could not start any of the machines that had been running just fine before. Just got the error message "'machine' could not initialize"

I restarted the host machine one more time, and now the machines start just fine.

Maybe this can help others, before resorting to other solutions.